# How do teleporters work in Steamworld Dig?

Tags: steamworld-dig

It's been a while since I played Steamworld Dig and I just picked it up again so I can finish it before starting the sequel. It looks like there are "natural" teleporters underground and also some purchasable ones that you can place anywhere along your route. And they all go to the same place above ground!

How does this work? Will it always deliver me to the most recent one I traveled back through? Or the deepest one? Or something else entirely? It doesn't appear that I can pick one to travel to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The teleporter on the surface will bring you back to your most recently used underground teleporter.**

To test this, I bought a teleporter from Cranky’s shop and placed it in the [Old World](http://steamworld.wikia.com/wiki/Old_World) (second area). This let me travel between the surface and the Old World.

I then backtracked to the teleporter in [Archaea](http://steamworld.wikia.com/wiki/Archaea) (first area). After using it, the surface teleporter let me travel between the surface and Archaea. This gave the same result after saving and quitting the game.

If you destroy your last used teleporter by digging the ground underneath, the surface teleporter will disappear until you use a another teleporter.